# cannot redeclare function error

Tags: php

I am receiving an error which I understand by meaning but do not know the solution to fix, the error I am receiving states:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare ExpandOptionType() (previously declared
>   in ...:269) in ... on line 269

Below is code:

```
foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {

    ?>

    <div class='lt-container'>

    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionNo[$key]) . ": " .  htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionContent[$key]); ?></p>

    <?php




    function ExpandOptionType($option) { //LINE 269 
      $options = explode('-', $option);
      if(count($options) > 1) {
        $start = array_shift($options);
        $end = array_shift($options);
        do {
          $options[] = $start;
        }while(++$start <= $end);
      }
      else{
        $options = explode(' or ', $option);
      }
      return implode(" ", $options);
    }
    ?>

    <p><?php echo ExpandOptionType(htmlspecialchars($arrOptionType[$key])); ?></p>


    </div>


    <?php

    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your function outside of your foreach loop...